# Generate unique ID for python object based on its attributes

Tags: python, object, attributes

Is there a way to generate a hash-like ID in for objects in python that is solely based on the objects' attribute values?  For example,

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

obj1 = test('a')
obj2 = test('a')

hash1 = magicHash(obj1)
hash2 = magicHash(obj2)
```

What I'm looking for is something where hash1 == hash2.  Does something like this exist in python?  I know I can test if obj1.name == obj2.name, but I'm looking for something general I can use on any object.

Answer (score 7):

You mean something like this?
Using the special method [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

```
class test:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
     def __hash__(self):
         return hash(self.name)

>>> hash(test(10)) == hash(test(20))
False
>>> hash(test(10)) == hash(test(10))
True
```

Comment: @Bastien, you are right. But that really depends on the application. For many cases hash could be enough.

Comment: It is not reccomended to return anything from __hash__(self) besides an int (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) as this will render the object apparently but incorrectly hashable (as in used in dicts)

Comment: If you have more than one attribute a tuple works too, e.g.:
  hash((self.first_name, self.last_name))

Answer (score 3):

**To get a unique comparison:**

To be unique you could serialize the data and then compare the serialized value to ensure it matches exactly.

Example:

```
import pickle

class C:
  i = 1
  j = 2

c1 = C()
c2 = C()
c3 = C()
c1.i = 99

unique_hash1 = pickle.dumps(c1) 
unique_hash2 = pickle.dumps(c2) 
unique_hash3 = pickle.dumps(c3) 

unique_hash1 == unique_hash2 #False
unique_hash2 == unique_hash3 #True
```

**If you don't need unique values for each object, but mostly unique:**

Note the same value will always reduce to the same hash, but 2 different values could reduce to the same hash.

You cannot use something like the built-in hash() function (unless you override `__hash__`)

```
hash(c1) == hash(c2) #False
hash(c2) == hash(c3) #False <--- Wrong
```

or something like serialize the data using pickle and then use zlib.crc32.

```
import zlib
crc1 = zlib.crc32(pickle.dumps(c1))
crc2 = zlib.crc32(pickle.dumps(c2))
crc3 = zlib.crc32(pickle.dumps(c3))
crc1 == crc2 #False
crc2 == crc3 #True
```

Comment: For the unique comparison you could also use zlib.compress to make the representation a little smaller if your objects are very big.

Comment: No, pickle is not good for hashing.  The results can vary, as described by Robert Brewer:
http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2007/11/03/pickle_dumps_not_suitable_for_hashing?blog=2

Comment: Not sure why but with CPython 2.5.1 I can't reproduce his behavior.  It always hashes to the same result for me.

Comment: @Matt Good: If you continue to read the comments on the blog post, you'll see that this problem is with cPickle not pickle.  And is due to reference counting.

Answer (score 2):

Have a lool at the [hash() build in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash) and the [`__hash__()` object method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). These may be just what you are looking for. You will have to implement `__hash__()` for you own classes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess

```
def hash_attr(ins):
 return hash(tuple(ins.__dict__.items()))
```

hashes anything instance based on its attributes.